# Imprecise 3D plot

Tags: plotting

I'm plotting the following figure:

[image]

There are two issues:

1. There is some noise around the edges of the section of the torus, see figure below
   [image]
2. The torus is not smooth enough (modulo rasterization of the image)
   [image]

Here's the coode producing the plot:

```
h = .3;
c = .9; 
T = 
 ParametricPlot3D[{(2 + c Cos[2 \[Pi] v]) Sin[
     2 \[Pi] u], (2 + c Cos[2 \[Pi] v]) Cos[2 \[Pi] u], 
   c Sin[2 \[Pi] v]}, {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1}, 
  RegionFunction -> 
   Function[{x, y, z}, Abs[x] >= h && y >= 0 || y <= 0], 
  Mesh -> {{0}}, PlotStyle -> {Opacity[.45], GrayLevel[0.95]}, 
  PlotPoints -> 100, MaxRecursion -> 8, Exclusions -> None, 
  ColorFunction -> ({Specularity[GrayLevel[0.2], 10], White} &)
  , Lighting -> {{"Directional", White, {-4, 0, 16}, {0, 0, 0}}}];

RT = ImplicitRegion[
   y^2 + (Sqrt[x^2 + z^2] - 2)^2 <= c^2 && 
    z >= 0, {{x, -5, 5}, {z, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}}];
RP1 = InfinitePlane[{h, 2, 0}, {{0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0}}];
S1 = RegionIntersection[RT, RP1];
S1D = DiscretizeRegion[S1, MaxCellMeasure -> {1 -> .01}, 
   MeshCellStyle -> {{2, All} -> Opacity[.8, Red]}];
RP2 = InfinitePlane[{-h, 2, 0}, {{0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0}}];
S2 = RegionIntersection[RT, RP2];
S2D = DiscretizeRegion[S2, MaxCellMeasure -> {1 -> .01}, 
   MeshCellStyle -> {{2, All} -> Opacity[.8, Blue]}];


Show[S1D, S2D, T, Axes -> False, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}, 
 ViewVector -> {-7, 0, 12}]
```

To solve both the problems I tried with `MaxRecursion`, `PlotPoints` and `Exclusions->None` in the plot `T`, but nothing worked. Do you know how to solve this?

Comment: What are your hardware specifications?. Your code give me an enough smooth plot.

Comment: Try `PlotPoints -> 100`.

Answer (score 2):

There two methods which can  speed up the generation of the two circles.

Method I

```
Clear["`*"];
h = .3;
c = .9;
surf = y^2 + (Sqrt[x^2 + z^2] - 2)^2 - c^2;
T = ParametricPlot3D[{(2 + c Cos[2 Pi v]) Sin[
      2 Pi u], (2 + c Cos[2 Pi v]) Cos[2 Pi u], c Sin[2 Pi v]}, {u, 0,
     1}, {v, 0, 1}, 
   RegionFunction -> 
    Function[{x, y, z, u, v}, Abs[x] >= h && y >= 0 || y <= 0], 
   Mesh -> {{0}}, PlotStyle -> {Opacity[.45], GrayLevel[0.95]}, 
   PlotPoints -> 20, MaxRecursion -> 8, Exclusions -> None, 
   ColorFunction -> ({Specularity[GrayLevel[0.2], 10], White} &), 
   Lighting -> {{"Directional", White, {-4, 0, 16}, {0, 0, 0}}}];
disks = ParametricPlot3D[{{h, 2, 0} + u*{0, 0, 1} + 
     v*{0, 1, 0}, {-h, 2, 0} + u*{0, 0, 1} + v*{0, 1, 0}}, {u, -3, 
    3}, {v, -3, 3}, 
   RegionFunction -> Function[{x, z, y}, surf <= 0 && z >= 0], 
   PlotStyle -> {Opacity[.8, Red], Opacity[.8, Blue]}, Mesh -> None];
Show[disks, T, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, 
 ViewVector -> {-7, 0, 12}, PlotRange -> All]
```

Method II

```
 Clear["`*"];
    h = .3;
    c = .9;
    surf = y^2 + (Sqrt[x^2 + z^2] - 2)^2 - c^2;
    render = {Specularity[GrayLevel[0.2], 10], Opacity[.45], 
       GrayLevel[0.95]};
    T = ParametricPlot3D[{(2 + c Cos[2 Pi v]) Sin[
          2 Pi u], (2 + c Cos[2 Pi v]) Cos[2 Pi u], c Sin[2 Pi v]}, {u, 0,
         1}, {v, 0, 1},
       MeshFunctions -> {Abs[#1] - h &, #2 &}, 
       MeshShading -> {{render, render}, {None, render}}, Mesh -> {{0}}, 
       BoundaryStyle -> None, MeshStyle -> None, PlotPoints -> 50, 
       Lighting -> {{"Directional", White, {-4, 0, 16}, {0, 0, 0}}}, 
       Boxed -> False, Axes -> False];
    disk1 = ParametricPlot3D[{h, 2, 0} + u*{0, 0, 1} + 
        v*{0, 1, 0}, {u, -4, 4}, {v, -4, 4}, Mesh -> {{0}, {0}, {0}}, 
       MeshFunctions -> {Function[{x, z, y}, surf], 
         Function[{x, z, y}, z]}, PlotPoints -> 50, 
       MeshShading -> {{None, None}, {Opacity[.8, Red], None}}, 
       BoundaryStyle -> None, MeshStyle -> None];
    disk2 = ParametricPlot3D[{-h, 2, 0} + u*{0, 0, 1} + 
        v*{0, 1, 0}, {u, -4, 4}, {v, -4, 4}, Mesh -> {{0}, {0}, {0}}, 
       MeshFunctions -> {Function[{x, z, y}, surf], 
         Function[{x, z, y}, z]}, PlotPoints -> 50, 
       MeshShading -> {{None, None}, {Opacity[.8, Blue], None}}, 
       BoundaryStyle -> None, MeshStyle -> None];
    Show[T, disk1, disk2, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, 
     ViewVector -> {-7, 0, 12}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]